# Selling something inside an application on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've heard there are some precautions to take to develop a market in an application.

I'm developing an application for a football club. I would like to integrate a kind of market to sell stadium seats.

Someone told me Apple will refuse the application if I integrate it directly inside the app (using Obj-C, communicating with PHP pages).

According to him, I should redirect the user to an external web page (using Safari app for example) to realize the transaction.

Apple does not really communicate about that kind of information.

Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use In App Purchase to buy "real life things" such as stadium seats : http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf

The only solution is to use an external payment solution.

The Movies Now app implements such a thing : http://moviesnowapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use only in-app purchases to sell anything in your app, otherwise Apple will reject your app.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Communicating with PHP pages will be rejected ? I can't create the connexion to the SQL database directly from the application (for security reasons).

Comment: You cannot include into your application anything, which allows user to buy something, only redirect to your site.

Comment: Exactly. So, Nonepse can do what he want only via redirect to his site.

Comment: So I should open Safari to redirect to my site ? or using UIWebView ?

Comment: Yes, you should use [UIApplication OpenURL:] to run safari separately, opening it inside UIWebView will lead to rejection.

Comment: Incorrect, UIWebView is totally acceptable for this purpose, in app purchases are only available for digital goods. Opening Safari is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if Apple will reject your app on these grounds. How can they know what your php pages are doing if you put them in a WebView? Also, think about services like Sky or Spotify that require a subscription. Apple do not take a cut on this, so you could set up a similar thing whereby your users have an account online that they can purchase tickets from and the iPhone is simply a thin client for your online services...

Comment: Actually I don't use PHP pages in UIWebView. My PHP pages receive POST params from the appli, make SQL request, display XML content. Then I download this XML content in the appli. By this way i can know if the seat is free, what's it's price, etc...

Comment: Oh I see, they are just a service? If you were to have a user purchase something I guess they would contact your web services some how? It's tricky because you'll need to handle the payment but if you made a web app (front end) and included it in a UIWebView, I don't know if apple would reject it because it's something that could go to anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use InApp purchase only to apply unlock functionality,and to use In App purchase there are certain scenarios which can be implemented.

You can find in detail about In App functionality on

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html

Secondly if you want to implement In App purchase,there is a very good tutorial which i found very helpful and was easily able to integrate inApp in my application and it was also later on approved by apple.

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Cheers

Comment: Yes you can't use in App for non digital goods.As for example a magazine subscription

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Apple in app purchase to purchase non digital goods, if you have an existing payment provider or user account you could use that, take a look at the eBay app which has Paypal integration