# Switching between apps

Tags: iphone, safari

In my previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/selling-something-inside-an-application)), I was told I have to redirect the user to Safari to finalize a bank transaction.

Once the transaction is finalized, I need to display a QRCode. I can't force the user to save it on is device.

I can still save this QRCode on a server, and download it on the device the next time the user opens my app.
Here is my problem : the user may not have internet access the next time he will open my app.

So, I would like to re-open my app once the transaction finalized. Is it possible to do it from Safari ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think it is important to note that such transactions do not need to be done in Safari, a  UIWebView within the app will work fine (and still be approved).

Comment: As Graham says it is possible to launch your app from Safari.  But why not just handle the transaction in a uiwebview inside your app, this way you can control exactly what's happening and provide a smoother user experience.

Comment: As explained in my previous Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/selling-something-inside-an-application), Apple will refuse any app which use UIWebView to realize a bank transaction. I have to launch it in Safari. I guess it's a security issue.

Comment: That's not true, as long as it's in a webview there should be no issue from apple.  I have had several apps approved that do this.

Comment: Did you read the entire discution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/iphone-selling-something-inside-an-application ? Everybody told there it's not possible to use a UIWebView. Well, you tell me it's possible. Who should I believe ?
Anyway, thanks for the vote down on a non-related question...

Comment: Another thing : what do you sell in your approved apps ?

Comment: Sorry I was getting a bit annoyed with all the mis-information flying around. I did read the other post and I think people were getting confused with in app purchases. Apple's guidelines state that when selling digital goods (ie extra points) in app purchases must be used, they cannot be used for physical goods. However they state no restriction on using another payment method for physical goods (ie UIWebView).

Comment: We have released a betting app that processes payment this way. Check out the eBay app, it does this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service must redirect the user to a URI that's handled by your app. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible:

What you could do is test to see whether the user has internet when they next open your app and alert
them that they need internet in order to complete a transaction (you will know that they attempted a
transaction based on their actions when they last left the app).

Also:
Is it not possible to perform the web-based transaction in a UIWebView?

Comment: As explained in my previous Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/selling-something-inside-an-application), Apple will refuse any app which use UIWebView to realize a bank transaction. I have to launch it in Safari. I guess it's a security issue.