# iOS payment gateway

Tags: iphone, ios, payment-gateway, payment, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selling something inside an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/selling-something-inside-an-application)

I'm really new to Objective-C programming, and I'm very interested in developing an iOS app. One of the major problems I am facing and that I've been researching is the opportunity of selling third-party products throughout my app. Haven't found anything about iOS payment gateways, and know if it is done through Apple IAP, they get 30% of the profit. Looking something like Amazon's app checkout.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by third party products? Apple license agreement covers in-app subscriptions (basically app upgrades), what you are describing doesn't sound like that at all. Also, the onerous changes to in-app subscription terms was basically dropped in June (http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/09/apple-reverses-course-on-in-app-subscriptions/). You need to consult a lawyer for questions like this. And eh, your question is off-topic for SO :)

Comment: There is an app called Splick It, which is allowing users to access several restaurants menus, placing an order and paying it in the app. Also Square performs this actions in-app too.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST use Apple's In-App Purchase system in order to sell anything from within your apps. You may not create your own payment system. Additionally, you cannot sell real-world items from within your app... whatever the user buys can only be used within the app itself (points, etc). And lastly, it is against Apple's Review Guidelines to put links to your own payment portal on your site. So, to summarize you must 1) use Apple's In-App Purchase system and 2) can only sell virtual items that can be used within your app.

Comment: You can create your own payment system (Amazon for ebooks sales), but you still owe Apple 30%.  You can also sell stuff offline and not pay apple 30% as long as you can't buy it from within the app and that includes a link to a website.  Again, see: Amazon.  But in the end, just use their API, so much simpler for everyone.