# iOS Guidelines in Implementing Payment within App Outside of In-App Purchase

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, payment, bank

Our company wants to know if it's possible to implement payment outside of In-App Purchase within an iOS app i.e. doing bank transactions and payments for bank services using a customer's account in the bank. Will Apple reject such kind of app knowing that this kind of payment is not covered by in-app purchase? Thanks.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613797/selling-something-inside-an-application

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the link answered all of our queries.